# Update view from observer pattern

Tags: ajax, jsf

I've been looking all over for this, but don't seem to find a good solution. Hopefully you guys can help me.

I'm trying to develop a web application with an internal messaging function. I'm currently using an observer pattern, with the idea of informing online users of a new message. But in order to change the view, I need to reload the page, or, using ajax, reload only part of the page. How do I go about doing this?

I only see two possibilities (if possible):

1) When the subject changes, the subject calls an update function on the observer. if I can trigger a partial update of the JSF from a bean, it would be preferable because this works in real time.

2) Loop some jquery to create a new request at certain intervals.

What am I missing and how do I do this? Thx in advance.

Comment: Are you using JSF? Which version of JSF and implementation you use?

Comment: Hi, I'm using JSF 2.2 straight up. I'm not using any other packages like pirmefaces or omnifaces. If necessary I can choose to change this. 

I'm running on glashfish 4.1 with JDK 8, java EE 7 web

Comment: JSF already comes with ajax support by using `<f:ajax>`. Also, you should work with Facelets, not JSP. I don't really understand how the process you describe works, but you may be good with partial rendering of the page, depending how much elements are going to be re-rendered and also tune the parameters being sent to the server.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I understand the confusion,[typo] I'm using facelets, and ajax. Look at the process this way. When a user logs in, they automatically register an observer with the subject (sessionscoped bean). For example, when user A sends a message to user B, the message gets stored in the database. The problem is in notifying user B of the new message. The subject therefor triggers an update function in the observer bean. So how do I get the view to refresh, preferably using ajax, if there is no user interaction on the view itself. For example here on stackoverflow a "1" shows with a new message

Comment: Oh ok. You can do that using a push notification framework. IceFaces, RichFaces and PrimeFaces come with components to achieve this. Otherwise, you will need to use a framework like atmosphere and roll your own implementation (I don't recommend doing this).

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. If you can post this as an answer, I will close the question, so you get the credits. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a push notification framework. IceFaces, RichFaces and PrimeFaces come with components to achieve this. Otherwise, you will need to use a framework like atmosphere and roll your own implementation (I don't recommend doing this).